# metrics-server show unknown on one node

Tags: metrics-server

It just happen on almalinux 9.0 server which I add into cluster today.
k8s version is 1.19.16

```
NAME             CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%     
k8s-dev-node1    110m         11%    2601Mi          104%             
k8s-dev-node8    160m         5%     3600Mi          56%         
k8s-dev-node9    105m         3%     2201Mi          34%         
k8s-dev-node16   <unknown>                           <unknown>               <unknown>               <unknown>
```

hostNetwork has been seted on metrics server deployment.
top pod is fine and get node stats is fine too.

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/k8s-dev-node16/proxy/stats/summary
{
 "node": {
  "nodeName": "k8s-dev-node16",
  "systemContainers": [
   {
    "name": "kubelet",
    "startTime": "2022-11-10T05:52:14Z",
    "cpu": {
     "time": "2022-11-10T09:42:50Z",
     "usageNanoCores": 17536218,
     "usageCoreNanoSeconds": 221415603000
    },
    "memory": {
     "time": "2022-11-10T09:42:50Z",
     "availableBytes": 8011243520,
     "usageBytes": 58892288,
     "workingSetBytes": 46686208,
     "rssBytes": 0,
     "pageFaults": 2555049,
     "majorPageFaults": 1
    }
   },
...
```

Comment: metrics-server have been update from 0.3.6 to 0.6.1, but no help.

Comment: I1111 09:12:32.557148       1 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://10.22.0.79:10250/metrics/resource 200 OK in 10 milliseconds
I1111 09:12:32.557324       1 decode.go:83] "Failed getting complete node metric" node="k8s-dev-node16" metric=&{StartTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Timestamp:2022-11-11 09:12:32.446 +0000 UTC CumulativeCpuUsed:0 MemoryUsage:0}